# scrapy using python3 logging module issue

Tags: python-3.x, logging, scrapy

I use scrapy 1.1.0, and I have 5 spiders in the "spiders" folder.

In every spider, I try to use python3 logging module. And the code structure like this :

```
import other modules
import logging
class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'special'

    def __init__(self):
        # other initializations
        # set log
        self.log = logging.getLogger('special')
        self.log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        logFormatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s')

        # file handler
        fileHandler = logging.FileHandler(LOG_PATH) # LOG_PATH has defined
        fileHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        fileHandler.setFormatter(logFormater)
        self.log.addHandler(fileHandler)

    # other functions
```

every spider has the same structure.When I run these spiders, I check the log file, they did exist, but their size are always 0 byte.

And the other question is that when I run one spider, it always generated two or more log files. Like I run `a` spider, and it will generate `a.log` and `b.log`.

Any answers would appreciate.

Comment: Do you use `self.log` to log anything? i.e. `self.log.warning('something')`? scrapy has it's own logger and so does every other component, What you are doing here is setting file handler etc. only for your logger.

Comment: @Granitosaurus All I want is to save scrapy output as a log file, and I know now scrapy(version 1.1.0)  has been deprecated alongside its functions in favor of explicit calls to the Python standard logging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set log file via `LOG_FILE` setting in `settings.py` or via command line argument `--logfile FILE`, i.e. `scrapy crawl myspider --logfile myspider.log`

[As described in the official docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html#command-line-options)

Comment: OK, it works! thanks. But if I want it both output to stdout and save as a file, what can I do?

Comment: You can just use basic unix output redirect: `scrapy crawl myspider 2>&1 > spider.log` where 2>&1 redirect stderr to stdout or if you want to see the output as well use `tee` with `scrapy crawl myspider 2>&1 | tee spider.log`